# Wygwam Content Elements conflict

Tags: custom-fields, wygwam, content-elements

I have field group with Wygwam and Content Elements. 
When I select Wysiwyg field in Content Elements, the Wygwam stops working, that is, buttons are not shown.

- EE: 2.6.1
- Wygwam: 2.7.1
- Content Elements: 1.3.1

here is screenshot http://screencast.com/t/GML5I1TNhXG

Comment: The problem still exist

 - EE 2.7.2 
 - Wygwam: 3.2.1
 - Content Elements: 1.6.3

here is creenshot http://screencast.com/t/rHzSc0mw

Answer (score 1):

Content Elements and Wygwam are not currently compatible.  The CE devs did contact us and we're working with them on that compatibility; but it isn't available yet.